# How to create Spring security Role on SAP Commerce cloud (Hybris)

Tags: java, spring-security, sap-commerce-cloud

I have a REST Controller that need to be checked with @PreAuthoriz("hasRole('ROLE_MYCUSTOMROLE'") but I dont know how to create a role in Hybirs.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Role in SAP Commerce can be added from backoffice.

login to backoffice , navigate to system -> OAuth -> OAuth Client
select your desired client, and edit the OAuth authorities
[image: OAuth authorities config in hybris backoffice]